# CUDA: Value of sum[0] changes with each execution

Tags: c, cuda, reduction

```
 __global__ void gpu_Heat (float *h, float *g, float * sum, int N) {
        int nbx, bx, nby, by;
        float diff = 0.0;
        nbx = (N-2)/blockDim.x;
        bx = nbx/gridDim.x;
        nby = (N-2)/blockDim.y;
        by = nby/gridDim.y;     
        unsigned int ii = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
        unsigned int jj = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
        unsigned int jid = (ii)*(N-2)+(jj);
         for (int i=1+ii*bx; i<=min((ii+1)*bx, N-2); i++) 
                    for (int j=1+jj*by; j<=min((jj+1)*by, N-2); j++) {
                    g[i*N+j]= 0.25 * (h[ i*N + (j-1)]+ 
                                 h[ i*N +(j+1) ]+
                                 h[ (i-1)*N + j]+ 
                                 h[ (i+1)*N + j]); 
                        diff = g[i*N+j] - h[i*N+j];
                        sum[(i-1)*(N-2)+(j-1)] = diff * diff;
                }
        __syncthreads();
        for(unsigned int s=((N-2)*(N-2))/2; s>0; s>>=1){    
            if(jid<s){
                sum[jid]+=sum[jid+s];           
            }
            __syncthreads();    

        }
    }
```

So my problem here is that the value of sum[0], that contains the end result of the parallel reduction changes with each execution of that kernel even though the inputs are the same and I don't know what I am doing wrong. If the same sum matrix is reduced in the CPU the execution is fine but with parallel reduction in GPU it is giving me problems.

```
    dim3 Grid = (16,16);
    dim3 Block = (16,16);
    gpu_Heat<<<Grid,Block>>>(dev_u, dev_uhelp, dev_sum, np);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();                        // wait for all threads to complete
    cudaErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(param.u,dev_u,np*np*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(param.uhelp,dev_uhelp,np*np*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy(sum,dev_sum,sum_size*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

I have shown here explicitly the block and grid parameters that are calculate by the code in the test that I am using. Thanks for answering

Comment: could you post the function call of the kernel, along with the grid and block parameters you are using to initialize the kernel, it would help in figuring out why it is failing

Comment: As above, but if it is changing every invocation, that means a race condition in your code!

Comment: @Bharat I have added the portion of the code you have asked.

Comment: @1-----1 yes it appears that there is. if I simply comment out the reduction part of the kernel and accumulate the sum matrix in the CPU it would be fine :/ Can't figure out where that problem is.

Comment: @1-----1 I have solved the problem. It was apparently because I was reducing the sum matrix in the same kernel and was not restricting the access of sum matrix to one block of threads. There was some kind of race condition generated because of that. Now I am using separate kernel calls to reduce "sum" and it is working correctly. Though, I am still not sure exactly why it was generating race condition.

Comment: @MB_CE: Please add your solution as an answer. It is perfectly OK to answer your own question and by doing so you remove the question from the unanswered list and leave something behind for the next person who has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are launching your GPU kernel with multiple blocks. While threads in one block are still computing their `sum` in the first `for` loop, some other blocks might be doing parallel reduction in the second `for` loop. These two `for` loops have data dependency. Because the scheduling of blocks over Streaming Multiprocessors happens behind the scene and may vary from one run to another, you get different results each time. `__syncthreads();` between `for` loops synchronizes threads inside the block but there's no mechanism or instruction for synchronization between multiple blocks unless return to host and issue another kernel.

In your case even if you simply separate `for` loops the results you'll get still can be wrong because your reduction happens across multiple blocks and again scheduling of blocks are not deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was under the wrong assumption that syncthreads() synchronizes all of the threads of the kernel much like cudaDeviceSynchronize().